# JavaScript | Get Data Ranging within Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a function that creates a new array of objects giving me all the data ranging `from` and `to` specified parameters.

i.e.

```
const data = [
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.1,
    dewPoint: 17.1,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:10:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.2,
    dewPoint: 17.2,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:20:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.3,
    dewPoint: 17.3,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:30:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.4,
    dewPoint: 17.4,
  }
]
```

The idea is to have a helper method that filters and outputs the data within `from` and `to` on a new array `[]`

```
function getValuesInRange(from, to) {
  let sortedArray = []
  let filteredValues = []
  let index = indexOf(from) // error => indexOf is not defined

  while (index < sortedArray.length) {
    const valueAtIndex = sortedArray[index]
    if (valueAtIndex.key >= from && valueAtIndex.key < to) {
      filteredValues.push(valueAtIndex.value)
      index++
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  console.log(filteredValues)
  return filteredValues
}

const fromDateTime = data[0].timestamp)
const toDateTime = data[2].timestamp)

getValuesInRange(fromDateTime, toDateTime)
```

- The method above currently errors as `indexOf is not defined`
- On `getValuesInRange()` am I massaging the data accordingly to produce the desired result here? could you also show me an ES6 equivalent of this effort?

Comment: it should be `array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])`

Comment: cld you please post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following way using `.getTime()` and `filter()`

> The **`getTime()`** method returns the number of milliseconds since  since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

```js
const data = [
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.1,
    dewPoint: 17.1,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:10:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.2,
    dewPoint: 17.2,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:20:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.3,
    dewPoint: 17.3,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:30:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.4,
    dewPoint: 17.4,
  }
]

function getData(arr,from,to){
  from = new Date(from).getTime();
  to = new Date(to).getTime();
  return arr.filter(obj => {
    let ms = new Date(obj.timestamp).getTime();
    return ms < to && ms > from
  })
}
console.log(getData(data,'2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z','2015-09-01T16:30:00.000Z'))
```

Comment: You've captured my goal exactly. I'm just wondering why do we need `getTime()` here? Thank you!

Comment: @Null isTrue `getTime()` return the milliseconds since `1970` so we use it to compare dates.

Comment: just so you know, your `run code snippet` stopped working for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much @Maheer Ali . Within your example how could I keep  `timestamp` just for  `from` and `to` proposes **and just** return the values for `{temperature: foo, dewPoint: bar}` on the new array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is a  method of the array object. It cannot be used standalone. It has to be used with an array

```
let index = arrayname.indexOf(from)
```

as it is not clear from you question in the above line of code replace the arrayname with the array in which you have to find the index of *from*

```js
const data = [
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:00:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.1,
    dewPoint: 17.1,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:10:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.2,
    dewPoint: 17.2,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:20:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.3,
    dewPoint: 17.3,
  },
  {
    timestamp: '2015-09-01T16:30:00.000Z',
    temperature: 27.4,
    dewPoint: 17.4,
  }
]


function getValuesInRange(from, to) {
  let sortedArray = []
  let filteredValues = []
  let index = arrayname.indexOf(from) // error => indexOf is not defined

  while (index < sortedArray.length) {
    const valueAtIndex = sortedArray[index]
    if (valueAtIndex.key >= from && valueAtIndex.key < to) {
      filteredValues.push(valueAtIndex.value)
      index++
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  console.log(filteredValues)
  return filteredValues
}

const fromDateTime = data[0].timestamp
const toDateTime = data[2].timestamp
getValuesInRange(fromDateTime, toDateTime)
```

Comment: by arrayname do you mean `data.indexOf(from)` in my example?